# When to use the Registry

Tags: vb.net, registry, settings

One of my VB.net applications started off to be fairly simple and (surprise) has grown significantly. I was using the Registry to save my limited number of settings, however that has now grown to where I felt I was abusing the Registry. I have converted most of my saved settings to XML files that have been working well. I would appreciate thoughts on saving the following to the Registry, I have been looking through threads on this and still am not sure if I should use files or the Registry:

- Paths to the user settings files. Currently the application looks for an
  XML file in a specific sub-folder of the users Documents folder for
  an XML file containing the paths.
- Window positions and sizes for forms (over 50 forms).
- Licensing data (licensing per machine).
- Application version.

Comment: I am afraid this question is really an opinion question. In the properties windows in design mode check out Application Settings Property Bindings.

Comment: I had hoped that there was documentation about Microsoft recommendations for Registry use, however I guess not. Bases on what I see of Microsoft's own use it is fair game for whatever you want to do.